# tableview 5 labels and 1 image in cell, best way

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

i am new in swift and I would like to know the best way to save user data and show in a tableview. Should I do with struct? Pls, give an example.
Tks

Comment: Please add some code you've tried or which did not work with some error, if you're asking for the best practice, there are a lot of swift tutorials online, perhaps [something like this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)?

Comment: I have not tried yet, and I only found tableview tutorials with 1 label or whatever. Thats why I am asking the best pratice for this with more. And about the link, i have already seen it, and I dont wanna populate via code.

Comment: To save user data you can use CoreData, plist or Database.

Comment: You can store your data as `NSDictionary` to `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: As the name implies, NSUserDefaults is only good to store defaults. That is: settings, small values, preferences. It is not a storage system, and should not be used for user data.

Comment: So which one should I use?